# Powershell : split excel into multiple excel with 2 headers

Tags: excel, powershell

I have an excel and I want to split that excel into multiple excels file and input file have 2 headers

For example in below excel :-
I will be using Test Folder ID as unique identifier and I am expecting 2 new excel files to be created ( working in my code ) . New excel file are not created with 2 header rows( not working )

[image]

This is the code I have so far. Requesting Help.

```
Function Create-Excel-Spreadsheet {
    Param($NameOfSpreadsheet)

    # open excel
    $excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
    $excel.visible = $true

    # add a worksheet
    $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add()
    $xl_wksht= $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
    $xl_wksht.Name = $NameOfSpreadsheet

    return $workbook
    $objexcel.Quit()
    \[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::FinalReleaseComObject($excel) | Out-Null
    Remove-Variable excel
}


$objexcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$wb = $objexcel.WorkBooks.Open("C:\temp\SPLIT\PanayaTestCaseUpload-Avi.xlsx") # Changing path for test.xlsx file.

$objexcel.Visible = $true
$objexcel.DisplayAlerts = $False
$ws = $wb.Worksheets.Item(1)

$usedRange = $ws.UsedRange
$usedRange.AutoFilter()

$totalRows = $usedRange.Rows.Count

$rangeForUnique = $usedRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize($UsedRange.Rows.Count-1) 
[string[]]$UniqueListOfRowValues = $rangeForUnique.Columns.Item(1).Value2 | sort -Unique
$xlFixedFormat = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat]::xlWorkbookDefault

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $UniqueListOfRowValues.Count; $i++) {
    $newRange = $usedRange.AutoFilter(1, $UniqueListOfRowValues[$i])

    $workbook = Create-Excel-Spreadsheet $UniqueListOfRowValues[$i]
    $wksheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)

    $range = $ws.UsedRange.Cells
    $range.Copy()

    $wksheet.Paste($wksheet.Range("A1"))
    $workbook.SaveAs("C:\temp\SPLIT\OUTPUT\" + $UniqueListOfRowValues[$i], $xlFixedFormat)
    $workbook.Close()
}

$objexcel.Quit()
\[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::FinalReleaseComObject($excel) | Out-Null
Remove-Variable excel
```

Comment: Have you ever used `ImportExcel`? https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel `Find-Module -Name ImportExcel | Install-Module`

Answer (score 0):

```
# Define the input and output file paths
$inputFilePath = "C:\temp\SPLIT\FullFile.xlsx"
#$outputDirectory = "C:\temp\SPLIT\OUTPUT\"
$outputDirectory = "\\xyz.com\network\public\Addon\Hello\OUTPUT\"

# open excel
$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$excel.visible = $false

# open the input workbook
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($inputFilePath)
$ws = $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)

# get the used range of the worksheet, including the first two rows
$usedRange = $ws.Range("A1", "AR" + $ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count)

# get the unique values in column AR
$uniqueValues = $usedRange.Columns.Item(44).Value2 | Sort-Object -Unique

# loop through each unique value and create a new workbook with the filtered data
foreach ($value in $uniqueValues) {
    $filterRange = $usedRange.AutoFilter(44, $value)
    $filteredRange = $usedRange.Offset(2).SpecialCells(12)

    # create a new workbook for the filtered data
    $newWorkbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add()
    $newWorksheet = $newWorkbook.Worksheets.Item(1)

    $newWorksheet.Name = "Tests"

    # copy the first and second rows of the input file and apply their formatting to the new worksheet
    $firstRow = $ws.Range("A1", "AR2")
    $firstRow.Copy()
    $newWorksheet.Range("A1:AR2").PasteSpecial(-4104)

    $secondRow = $ws.Range("A2", "AR2")
    $secondRow.Copy()
    $newWorksheet.Range("A2:AR2").PasteSpecial(-4104)

    # copy the filtered data to the new worksheet
    $filteredRange.Copy()
    $newWorksheet.Range("A3").PasteSpecial(-4163)

    # save the new workbook
    $newWorkbook.SaveAs($outputDirectory + $value + ".xlsx")
    $newWorkbook.Close()
}
# clean up the Excel application
$workbook.Close()
$excel.Quit()
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::FinalReleaseComObject($excel) | Out-Null
Remove-Variable excel
```